java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/MarkerFactory
my pom.xml file
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.12</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

error:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/MarkerFactory [in thread "Editor Parsing Loop (21-b15c9b7692b2764be5a997d056e2283b72ae9131)"]
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Slf4jLogFactory.(Slf4jLogFactory.java:255)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:419)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.lambda$newFactory$3(LogFactory.java:1432)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.newFactory(LogFactory.java:1431)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:925)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:987)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.(AbstractVerifier.java:61)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:44)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:46)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.GlobalState.newConnectionManager(GlobalState.java:169)
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.LocalState.(LocalState.java:57)
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.(HttpTransporter.java:197)
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporterFactory.newInstance(HttpTransporterFactory.java:95)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:94)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:128)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:172)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:122)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:536)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:449)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:261)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:243)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:278)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:197)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveAlways(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:152)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.resolveArtifact(MavenEmbedder.java:414)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.MavenJsfReferenceImplementationProvider.artifactPathFor(MavenJsfReferenceImplementationProvider.java:80)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.facelets.FaceletsLibrarySupport.parseLibraries(FaceletsLibrarySupport.java:361)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.facelets.FaceletsLibrarySupport._findLibraries(FaceletsLibrarySupport.java:325)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.facelets.FaceletsLibrarySupport.findLibraries(FaceletsLibrarySupport.java:270)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.facelets.FaceletsLibrarySupport.getNamespaceLibraryMapping(FaceletsLibrarySupport.java:173)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.JsfSupportImpl.getLibraries(JsfSupportImpl.java:233)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.el.JsfVariablesModel.initModel(JsfVariablesModel.java:97)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.el.JsfVariablesModel.(JsfVariablesModel.java:80)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.el.JsfVariablesModel.getModel(JsfVariablesModel.java:66)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.el.JsfELVariableResolver$2.run(JsfELVariableResolver.java:247)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callUserTask(TaskProcessor.java:586)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:132)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:116)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(TaskProcessor.java:181)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(TaskProcessor.java:178)
at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.utils.FileChangedManager.priorityIO(FileChangedManager.java:153)
at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.providers.ProvidedExtensions.priorityIO(ProvidedExtensions.java:335)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.nb.DataObjectEnvFactory.runPriorityIO(DataObjectEnvFactory.java:118)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.Utilities.runPriorityIO(Utilities.java:67)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.runUserTask(TaskProcessor.java:178)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager.parse(ParserManager.java:83)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.el.JsfELVariableResolver.getAllJsfVariables(JsfELVariableResolver.java:240)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor.el.JsfELVariableResolver.getVariables(JsfELVariableResolver.java:140)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.ELVariableResolvers$4.get(ELVariableResolvers.java:127)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.ELVariableResolvers$4.get(ELVariableResolvers.java:121)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.CompilationCache.getOrCache(CompilationCache.java:35)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.ELVariableResolvers.getVariables(ELVariableResolvers.java:119)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.ELTypeUtilities.getIdentifierType(ELTypeUtilities.java:600)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.ELTypeUtilities.access$100(ELTypeUtilities.java:73)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.ELTypeUtilities$TypeResolverVisitor.visit(ELTypeUtilities.java:852)
at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:222)
at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:225)
at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:225)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.ELTypeUtilities.resolveElement(ELTypeUtilities.java:169)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.ELTypeUtilities.resolveElement(ELTypeUtilities.java:158)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.hints.Identifiers$1.visit(Identifiers.java:97)
at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:222)
at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:225)
at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:225)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.hints.Identifiers.run(Identifiers.java:83)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.hints.ELHintsProvider$1.run(ELHintsProvider.java:70)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.hints.ELHintsProvider$1.run(ELHintsProvider.java:62)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.MimeTask.run(MimeTask.java:60)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callUserTask(TaskProcessor.java:586)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$MimeTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:364)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$MimeTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:347)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(TaskProcessor.java:181)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(TaskProcessor.java:178)
at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.utils.FileChangedManager.priorityIO(FileChangedManager.java:153)
at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.providers.ProvidedExtensions.priorityIO(ProvidedExtensions.java:335)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.nb.DataObjectEnvFactory.runPriorityIO(DataObjectEnvFactory.java:118)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.Utilities.runPriorityIO(Utilities.java:67)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.runUserTask(TaskProcessor.java:178)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager.parse(ParserManager.java:318)
at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource.runUserActionTaskImpl(JavaSource.java:433)
at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource.runUserActionTask(JavaSource.java:425)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.el.hints.ELHintsProvider.computeHints(ELHintsProvider.java:62)
at org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.infrastructure.HintsTask$1.run(HintsTask.java:114)
at org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.infrastructure.HintsTask$1.run(HintsTask.java:76)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callUserTask(TaskProcessor.java:586)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:132)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:116)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(TaskProcessor.java:181)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(TaskProcessor.java:178)
at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.utils.FileChangedManager.priorityIO(FileChangedManager.java:153)
at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.providers.ProvidedExtensions.priorityIO(ProvidedExtensions.java:335)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.nb.DataObjectEnvFactory.runPriorityIO(DataObjectEnvFactory.java:118)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.Utilities.runPriorityIO(Utilities.java:67)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.runUserTask(TaskProcessor.java:178)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager.parse(ParserManager.java:83)
at org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.infrastructure.HintsTask.run(HintsTask.java:69)
at org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.infrastructure.HintsTask.run(HintsTask.java:52)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callParserResultTask(TaskProcessor.java:561)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$RequestPerformer.run(TaskProcessor.java:786)
at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:288)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$RequestPerformer.execute(TaskProcessor.java:702)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$CompilationJob.run(TaskProcessor.java:663)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1420)
at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:287)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2035)
I have created java file for Client service

package com.onlinExam.OnlineExam;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class MyHttpClientService {
    
    public void performHttpRequest() throws Exception {
        // Create HttpClient instance using HttpClientBuilder
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            // Define the HTTP request
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://example.com/api/resource");

            // Execute the request
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
                // Process the response
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                // Handle response...
            }
        }
    }
}

